# Django Test Client Post Request Fails to Redirect

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

My django.test Client returns a response with status code, 200, when I made a post request instead of redirecting with a status code, 302.

I am using Django 2.2.4 with Python 3.7.3.

No login is required (as addressed by [Why does Django Redirect Test Fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064832/why-does-django-redirect-test-fail)) neither does setting the follow and secure parameters to True (as addressed by [Django test client POST command not registering through 301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546354/django-test-client-post-command-not-registering-through-301-redirect))

I noticed that the same problem affects my update view. It doesn't redirect when I call the Django Test Client with a put method.
(I didn't include this code to avoid verbosity).

Finally, I noticed that the page redirect works when I `python manage.py runserver` and then visit the page to create a new Book instance.

Here's the test:

```py
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse
...

class TestDashboardViews(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.book_list_url = reverse("dashboard-home")
        self.book_create_url = reverse("dashboard-upload-book")
        self.another_demo_book_kwargs = {
            "title": "Demo Title",
            "author": "Demo Author",
            "subject": "Another Demo Subject",
            "details": "Another Demo Details",
            "file": "path/to/another/demo/file"
        }
        ...

    def test_book_create_view_using_post_method(self):
        response = self.client.post(self.book_create_url, self.another_demo_book_kwargs)

        self.assertRedirects(response, self.book_list_url)
        ...
```

Here's the affected view:

```py
class BookCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Book
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'subject', 'details', 'file']
    success_url = reverse_lazy("dashboard-home")
```

Here's the model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def author_title_path(self, filename):
        return "files/{author}/{filename}".format(author=slugify(self.author), filename=filename)

    file = models.FileField(upload_to=author_title_path)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        title_by_author = "{title} by {author}".format(title=self.title, author=self.author)
        self.slug = slugify(title_by_author)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and here are my urls:

```py
from django.urls import path
from dashboard.views import BookListView, BookCreateView, BookUpdateView, BookDeleteView

urlpatterns = [
    path("", BookListView.as_view(), name="dashboard-home"),
    path("add_book/", BookCreateView.as_view(), name="dashboard-upload-book"),
    path("edit_book/<slug>/", BookUpdateView.as_view(), name="dashboard-edit-book"),
    path("delete_book/<slug>/", BookDeleteView.as_view(), name="dashboard-delete-book")
]
```

My test fails with this error:

```py
...
AssertionError: 200 != 302 : Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302)
...
```

Please, help.

Comment: Your form is presumably not valid. You should examine the response to find out why; most likely, the value for `file` is not correct (it should be an actual file, not a path).

Comment: Likely it's not valid because you're not uploading a file. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170425/how-to-unit-test-file-upload-in-django) to learn how to upload files in a unit test.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman.

The problem was truly with the file.

Comment: Your link had the solution I needed @dirkgroten.

Opening the file inside a `with` statement and passing the open file as the file parameter was the answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Roseman and dirkgroten helped identify the problem in the comments.

I recommend checking out the question dirkgroten refered to ([how to unit test file upload in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170425/how-to-unit-test-file-upload-in-django))

The problem was with the file field in the `self.another_demo_book_kwargs` created in the setup of the test.

The file field expects an actual file, not just a path.

This:

```py
self.another_demo_book_kwargs = {
            "title": "Demo Title",
            "author": "Demo Author",
            "subject": "Another Demo Subject",
            "details": "Another Demo Details",
            "file": "path/to/another/demo/file"
        }
```

should be replaced with this:

```py
with open(ABSOLUTE_FILE_PATH) as file_object:
            data = {
                "title": "Demo Title",
                "author": "Demo Author",
                "subject": "Another Demo Subject",
                "details": "Another Demo Details",
                "file": file_object
            }
            response = self.client.post(self.book_create_url, data)
```